# How do I format the background color for a positioned block of text?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a positioned Text element that sits on top of an Image element in a Stack. I'd like to apply a simple background color to that Text element, so that it frames the text like a caption box:

[image: desired output]

I can do this by inserting a Container as another positioned child in that Stack. But I'd have to recalculate the width every time the text string changes, which is sub-optimal. Is there a better way?

[image: one poor approach]

```
var stack = new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Image.asset ( // background photo
      "assets/texture.jpg",
      fit: ImageFit.cover,
      height: 600.0,
    ),
    new Positioned ( // headline
      child: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration (
          backgroundColor: Colors.black
        ),
      ),
      left: 0.0,
      bottom: 108.0,
      width: 490.0,
      height: 80.0,
    ),
    new Positioned (
      child: new Text (
        "Lorem ipsum dolor.",
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue[500],
          fontSize: 42.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900
        )
      ),
      left: 16.0,
      bottom: 128.0,
    )
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just nest the Text element as a child **within** the Container that has the BoxDecoration (i.e. background color); the Container will stretch to fit the Text inside. Additionally, one can specify padding for that Container, which eliminates the need to hardcode a width/height for the box.

```
var stack = new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Image.asset ( // background photo
      "assets/texture.jpg",
      fit: ImageFit.cover,
      height: 600.0,
    ),
    new Positioned ( // headline
      child: new Container(
        child: new Text (
          "Lorem ipsum dolor.",
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue[500],
            fontSize: 42.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900
          )
        ),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration (
          backgroundColor: Colors.black
        ),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0),
      ),
      left: 0.0,
      bottom: 108.0,
    ),
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 7):

As of Flutter 0.10.3 has changed BoxDecoration. backgroundColor: is no longer a valid property. It is now color:.

Comment: `color` controls the color of the text itself. This question is about setting the background color of the `Text` widget.

Comment: James talked about changing the `color` of the `Container` , not the `Text` . as of Flutter 1.0.0 you can do this to change the text background color: `style: TextStyle(background: Paint()..color = Color(0xFF3b9c00), ),` . got this from this [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20430)